# How to get inside of this thin white border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Original image :

[image]

I need to get inside of this white border selection how to do it?

Here the selection

[image: http://orig10.deviantart.net/ef62/f/2015/174/6/4/inside_of_here_by_monstermmorpg-d8yhv3e.png]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the white border
2. Press "Select" in the top menu, then "modify"
3. Try Border, Expand and Contract. This way you can play around with your selection a bit.

I am however not sure what result you are looking for. If you want to make a selection of the content inside the white border you can follow the steps above.